# Org-mode: How to place a table left aligned on the paper?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-table

I'm very new to Latex or PDF-export.
I try to export an Org-document with tables.
The problem is, that I cannot (or better: don't know how to) place them left aligned.
The problem seems to come from some default Latex command at the exported .tex:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Does anyone know how to override this 'center'ing w/o any time editing the generated .tex?

Best regards,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all tables to be always left-aligned, then setting `org-latex-tables-centered`as @gigiair's answer suggests is the right way to go: you customize it once and never worry about it again.

If you want to change the centering behavior only for a single file, then the way to do it is to use the `#+BIND` mechanism. Add the following line to the top of your file:

```
#+BIND: org-latex-tables-centered nil
```

That will set the local value of `org-latex-tables-centered` to nil *during export only*.

In order for this to work however, you will have to enable the BIND mechanism by setting (or customizing) the variable `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t`. I find the BIND mechanism useful, so I set it permanently.

Finally, if you want to change the centering of a single table, you can set an attribute for that table only:

```
#+NAME: cubes
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
|  a | a^{3} |
|----+-------|
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     8 |
...
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick. Now it works perfect!
That is the cool way to do it with the 'BIND' keyword.
I wasn't aware of that feature in Org.
That may be helpful also in other situations where I don't want to change variables globally.

Comment: @chris-tian: if this or any other answer that has been provided has indeed answered your question satisfactorily, please [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). To find out more about how the site works, click on the `?` icon in the upper right of the page and read the topics in the `Help Center`.

Answer (score 0):

You can eval

```
(setq org-latex-tables-centered nil)
```

or customize the variable org-latex-tables-centered

To customize the latex export, you can browse Org Export LaTeX

```
(customize-group "org-export-latex")
```